# what does "벌벌 기고" mean in this case?

Tags: vocabulary

돈 몇 푼에도 벌벌 기고 쩔쩔매는 본인을 절대 닮지를 말래

rap lyrics from high school rapper 
https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=ymr772&logNo=220969098780&proxyReferer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a combination of `벌벌` and `기다`. According to the [Naver Korean-English Dictionary](http://m.endic.naver.com):

---

#### 벌벌

*Adverb*.

1. shakingly; shiveringly
2. **with crawling movement** (Reference: often used as 벌벌 기다)

---

### 기다

*Verb*.

1. crawl; creep
2. go very slowly
3. *(slang)* **to act humble or cowardly before someone; cringe; grovel**

---

So we can conclude that the sentence can be translated to

> 돈 몇 푼에도 벌벌 기고 쩔쩔매는 본인을 절대 닮지를 말래
>   He says not to follow him always so thrifty.

Comment: thx. i also checked out the japanese defintions on naver. now it's pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

1) 벌벌 기다 : Creep like a insect.

2) 벌벌 떨다 : tremble or flutter

In winter, I was shivering

겨울에 벌벌 떨었다 (= 부들부들 떨었다)

@ Comparing 뻘뻘